# Différence entre "constituer" et "composer"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Existe-t-il une différence entre les deux verbes "constituer" et "composer"?

Answer (score 3):

Ces deux verbes sont parfois synonymes mais ne sont pas pour autant toujours interchangeables. Par exemple :

- Mozart a composé des symphonies, il ne les a pas constituées.
- Les crues constituent un danger pour les habitations en zone inondable, elles ne composent pas un danger.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour, jlliagre a expliqué le cas où les mots ne sont pas interchangeables mais lorsque cela est possible les deux mots ont, en fait, des définitions bien différentes (on le voit très bien en programmation).

**Constituer :**

Ici on parle d'agrégation. Un élément (*ex: voiture*) peut être **constitué** de plusieurs autres (*ex: moteur, roues...*). 
Les différents **éléments peuvent exister indépendamment** les uns des autres. Les éléments constituants (*roues*) peuvent exister et être créés, avant qu'ils ne constituent l'élément global (*voiture*).

**ex.** on peut fabriquer une roue, la voiture en sera constituée. Mais on peut aussi enlever une roue de la voiture, ça ne détruira ni la voiture ni la roue. Donc : une voiture est constituée de roues, d'un moteur, de sièges, etc.

**Composer :**

Ici les **éléments ont une relation existentielle**. Si on enlève ne serait-ce qu'un élément composant, le tout est détruit.

**ex.** Un animal est composé d'une tête, si on enlève la tête l'animal est mort et la tête ne fonctionnera pas même si on la donne à un autre corps animal (…lol).

*Dans les deux cas il y a un rapport hiérarchique, les éléments composants ou constituants ne peuvent être utilisés que dans l'élément duquel ils font partie.*

Vieux sujet mais je me permets de donner une réponse à cette question.

Comment: C'est bien intéressante cette différence-ci, même s'il s'agit d'une utilisation un peu technique. Merci d'une réponse réfléchie.

Comment: (Mais pourriez-vous clarifier un point : si les éléments constituants peuvent être enlevés de l'élément global, et quant à l'exemple de la voiture pourraient même être réemployés, pourquoi dites-vous qu'eux également "ne peuvent être utilisés que dans l'élément dont ils font partie"? Peut-être : Les composants que dans cet élément global même, les constituants que dans un élément de ce type ?)

Answer (score 2):

**Pour continuer dans l'exemple de la voiture, par rapport au [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22341/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-constituer-et-composer#comment48569_24813) de Luke :**

Une roue peut exister indépendamment de la carcasse de la voiture, mais on ne peut pas « l'utiliser » si elle n'en fait pas partie. Une roue seule, ne sert à rien. Tout comme une tête seule ne sert à rien (pour l'autre exemple).

Après il est vrai qu'on peut vérifier qu'un moteur marche, en externe. Mais pour le « conduire » il faut qu'il soit dans une voiture, avec tout ce qui la constitue, pour que ce moteur ait une utilité.

Donc pour avoir une utilité, pouvoir être utilisés, les éléments, doivent faire partie d'un tout (élément global), qu’ils soient constituant ou composant. Cette dernière distinction ne différencie que leur particularité existentielle, pas leur possibilité d'utilisation.

***Les composants que dans cet élément global même, les constituants que dans un élément de ce type ?*** - C'est ça, mais pour les constituants, ils peuvent aussi être utilisés dans d'autres types, comme ils existent séparément. Ils devront juste être mis dans un élément global avant utilisation (*les roues peuvent être ajoutées à un robot par exemple*).

Comment: Bonjour ! Pour pouvoir commenter, il vous faut [50 pts](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). C'est assez facile de les obtenir, en posant quelques [questions](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (5pts par vote) ou en répondant à quelques [réponses](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (10pts par vote positif)... Il vaut sans doute la peine d'activer un correcteur dans votre fureteur pour l'orthographe et de vous assurer d'avoir une configuration clavier adaptée à la langue. Merci !